# ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2 on using LAST_INSERT_ID

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, vuejs2, last-insert-id

I am new to vuejs and express, and I've been wondering how to get the `GuestID` from the `Guest` Table to the foreign key `GuestID` in my `reservations` table.

```
app.post('/create',(req,res,next)=>{
    var mysql = require('mysql')
    var connection = mysql.createConnection(config)
    var sql = "INSERT INTO `guest` SET ?"
    connection.query(sql,req.body,(err,results,fields)=>{
        connection.end()
        if(err){
            next(err)
        }else{
            res.json([true,results.insertId])
        }
    })
})


app.post('/book',(req,res,next)=>{
    var mysql = require('mysql')
    var connection = mysql.createConnection(config)
    var sql = "INSERT INTO `reservation` SET `GuestID`=LAST_INSERT_ID(),`RoomID`=?,`AdultCount`=?,`KidCount`=?,`CheckInDate`=?,`CheckOutDate`=?"
    var RoomID = req.body.RoomID;
    var AdultCount = req.body.AdultCount;
    var KidCount = req.body.KidCount;
    var CheckInDate = req.body.CheckInDate;
    var CheckOutDate = req.body.CheckOutDate;
    connection.query(sql,[RoomID,AdultCount,KidCount,CheckInDate,CheckOutDate],(err,results,fields)=>{
        connection.end()
        if(err){
            next(err)
        }else{
            res.json([true,results])
        }
    })
})
```

Then I get this Error:

> Error: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`booking`.`reservation`, CONSTRAINT `reservation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`GuestID`) REFERENCES `guest` (`GuestID`))

Comment: Error message means that you try to insert record into `booking` with the value of `reservation` which is absent in `guest` table. The reason is simple - `LAST_INSERT_ID()` has a connection scope. But in each `app.post` you open its own connection - so the value of last inserted ID in one connection is not available in another. Function returns zero, there is no guest with this ID, query fails.

Comment: Possible solutions: 1) Use one connection for both queries; 2) Use SELECT for to get user's ID instead of LAST_INSERT_ID().

Comment: @Akina for number 1, is it like putting two `var sql`'s in one `app.post`? And I don't think I can use 2 either

Comment: You may also: create a variable out of these code fragments (it is to be accessible in both), select `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in 1st block immediately after `INSERT INTO guest` execution and store it into this variable, then use this value in 2nd code block.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Akina I tried to go search for queries on one connection. I saw a post where you can put multiple statements in express using the `multipleStatements` in the connection and made my code like this:

```
app.post('/book',(req,res,next)=>{
    var mysql = require('mysql')
    var connection = mysql.createConnection(config)
    var sql = "INSERT INTO `guest` SET `FirstName`=?,`LastName`=?,`Email`=?,`ContactNumber`=?;SET @GuestID:=LAST_INSERT_ID();INSERT INTO `reservation` SET `GuestID`=@GuestID,`RoomID`=?,`AdultCount`=?,`KidCount`=?,`CheckInDate`=?,`CheckOutDate`=?"
    var FirstName = req.body.FirstName;
    var LastName = req.body.LastName;
    var Email = req.body.Email;
    var ContactNumber = req.body.ContactNumber;
    var RoomID = req.body.RoomID;
    var AdultCount = req.body.AdultCount;
    var KidCount = req.body.KidCount;
    var CheckInDate = req.body.CheckInDate;
    var CheckOutDate = req.body.CheckOutDate;
    connection.query(sql,[FirstName,LastName,Email,ContactNumber,RoomID,AdultCount,KidCount,CheckInDate,CheckOutDate],(err,results,fields)=>{
        connection.end()
        if(err){
            next(err)
        }else{
            res.json([true,results])
        }
    })
})
```

I mean its long but it works lol, but if you guys got something more efficient than this then please let me know